# sentiment analysis for English vs Urdu

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am new to NLP and have started working in Sentiment Analysis in one of the resource-poor languages - Urdu. I have a basic question. Work which has already been done in English is mature.How my working in sentiment analysis for the Urdu language can make a contribution as Both English and Urdu sentiment Analysis use the same machine learning algorithms. How the Sentiment Analysis techniques for English make them different from other languages. In simple words can I directly apply the Sentiment Analysis techniques developed for the English language on Urdu.

Comment: this is kind of a vague question - there are several approaches to sentiment analysis, so which one are you considering? And since most of them rely on some kind of English word list, this part at least will have to be changed when looking at a different language.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know that there is machine learning based approach like the application of machine learning algorithms for SA task, Lexicon based approach, and hybrid approach. If I ask like this that a lot of work has already been done on sentiment analysis for the English language if applying above mentioned techniques on some other language make some sense. or is this worth a work?

Comment: Is there anyone to clarify this question?